# ARKit/SceneKit Screenshot Without Rendered/Virtual Content

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I have a pretty straightforward ARKit demo app in which I place a few objects into view with labeling. I'm currently using the `snapshot()` function on `ARSCNView` to get a screenshot of the video input with all my rendered objects in view.

However, I'd like to get a UIImage of just the raw camera input, without any extra rendered objects on top of that, preferably in the same resolution as what's displayed on the screen. I'm not sure what the best way to do that would be. Is there a way to strip the rendered content? should I tie into the camera feed directly?

Currently it looks a little something like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

    var nodeModel:SCNNode!
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let scene = SCNScene()
        sceneView.scene = scene
        let modelScene = SCNScene(named: ...
        nodeModel =  modelScene?.rootNode.childNode(...
        ...
        self.view.addSubview( ...
    }

    ...some ARKit stuff...some model stuff...
}

extension ViewController {
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRenderScene scene: SCNScene, atTime time: TimeInterval) {
        if self.captureButton.capturing && time > self.captureTime {
            captureScreenshot(scene)            
            self.captureTime = time + TimeInterval(0.1)
        }
    }

    func captureScreenshot(_ scene: SCNScene){
        DispatchQueue.main.async() {
            let screenshot = self.sceneView.snapshot()
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement the optional `ARSessionDelegate` method:

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)
```

`ARFrame` has a property `captureImage` which is a `CVPixelBuffer` which you can then convert to a `UIImage` like so:

```
import VideoToolbox

extension UIImage {
    public convenience init?(pixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer) {
        var cgImage: CGImage?
        VTCreateCGImageFromCVPixelBuffer(pixelBuffer, nil, &cgImage)

        guard let cgImage = cgImage  else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice trick, but note you don’t necessarily need the delegate method to get the frame — you can also get the `currentFrame` from the `ARSession`, which you can in turn get from the view.

Comment: Also note this bit from the docs for that VideoToolbox function: *The source CVPixelBuffer may be retained for the lifetime of the CGImage.* Holding onto pixel buffers vended by the camera system is dangerous, because the camera recycles buffers from a pool, and if you retain too many for too long it’ll run out of buffers it can use, suspending the capture session and your `ARSession` on top of it. If you use that function for a screenshot, export your PNG/JPEG/HEIF image data and then lose the `CGImage` right away. (Create a new image from the data if you want to show it in your UI.)

Comment: This is actually the exact solution I came to yesterday, and I think we even found the UIImage extension from the same place.  :)